# Strokes created with python cannot be selected or edited

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil

Blender 3.2.2

```
from bpy import context as C, data as D, types as T, props as P, utils as U

class CreateLine(T.Operator):
    bl_idname: str = "object.create_line"
    bl_label: str = "Create Line"

    def execute(self, context: T.Context):
        gp: T.GreasePencil = D.objects["Stroke"].data
        layer: T.GPencilLayer = gp.layers.new(name="abc")
        frame: T.GPencilFrame = layer.frames.new(1)
        stroke: T.GPencilStroke = frame.strokes.new()
        stroke.display_mode = "2DSPACE"
        stroke.line_width = 10
        stroke.points.add(2)
        stroke.points[0].co = (0, 0, 0)
        stroke.points[1].co = (1, 0, 0)
        return {"FINISHED"}

def register():
    U.register_class(CreateLine)

def unregister():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: Might be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. Change `2DSPACE` to `3DSPACE`.

https://developer.blender.org/T100607

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code.
Here it is.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context as C, data as D, types as T, props as P, utils as U

class CreateLine_PT_new(T.Panel):
    bl_label = "Create Line"
    bl_idname = "PT_CreateLine"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Create Line"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.operator("object.create_line")


class CreateLine(T.Operator):
    bl_idname: str = "object.create_line"
    bl_label: str = "Create Line"

    def execute(self, context):
        ob = bpy.context.object.data.name
        gp = bpy.data.grease_pencils[ob]
        layer = gp.layers.new(name="abc")
        frame = layer.frames.new(1)
        stroke = frame.strokes.new()
        stroke.display_mode = "2DSPACE"
        stroke.line_width = 10
        stroke.points.add(2)
        stroke.points[0].co = (0, 0, 0)
        stroke.points[1].co = (1, 0, 0)
        return {"FINISHED"}

def register():
    U.register_class(CreateLine_PT_new)
    U.register_class(CreateLine)

def unregister():
    U.unregister_class(CreateLine_PT_new)
    U.unregister_class(CreateLine)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Here is the result!

[image]